# How to add a project reference to a .csproj file in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, csproj

In an already existing project I have a reference to another project by pointing to its .csproj file (highlighted in red):
[image]

Today I tried to do the same in a new solution/project by right clicking *Dependencies* - *Add Project Reference...* However, clicking *Browse* there doesn't allow me to add a .csproj file, note the file extension filter:
[image]

If I ignore the filter and input the .csproj manually, it first seems like I can add it, but when I then click OK, I get the error "The reference is invalid or unsupported".

[image]

So, how can I add a project reference to a .csproj file? Wondering if this changed in newer versions of Visual Studio. I am on latest stable 17.2.3 (2022 Community)

Comment: That's not what `Browse` is for. You can add project references only to the projects in your solution. `Component Files` refers to *COM* component files. I don't remember ever adding a project reference through the `Browse` button

Answer (score 3):

You can add the project to your solution and then reference it from there.

You can also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47634380/adding-reference-of-another-external-project-in-a-solution).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).